# How to know which segue was used to load the view

Tags: button, storyboard

I have a TableView with two segue that go to the same view but in different ways. The first way is by adding a button in the Navigation Bar and the second way is with a button  accessory from a cell in the TableView.

When I click on the Add button I add an empty contact.
When I click on the attachment button I edit my contact.

Now, in the second view when I click on Save I make a unwind segue and I save my contact.

My problem is when I want to edit one contact I always create a new contact so I make a copy every time I click Save because it is the same method that is called: - (IBAction) saveUnwind (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *) segue {...}

So I thought to make two unwind methods and have a ID for my two segues but we can only have a unwind segue  by button.

So how can I have two actions or two unwind action on the same button?

Thank!

Pictures :

http://idzr.org/26ns
http://idzr.org/3cxw

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method i.e `-(IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender;`, assign the buttons to that method, and then call `- (IBAction) saveUnwind(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *) segue {...}` in it

```
-(IBAction)someMethod(id)sender
{
   // get the sender tag

   // filter which button was used

   // call [self saveUnwind:StoryboardPopoverSegue];
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the problem is that method is called by the button in the second view controller class and the unwind method is declared in table view class. Edit : The (IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender; I declare this method in my second view controller and I need to know which buttons was selected in the table view class. I need to add tags on these buttons? I think the solution is to make a method like you did and know which segue was used from this view